# How does crypto/rand generate a secure random number?

Tags: go, random, cryptography

I started to geek out and I wanted to see how https://golang.org/src/crypto/rand/rand_unix.go works on the inside.

I wanted to see when it generates rands from `dev/random` (more secure) and when it generates from `dev/urandom`(less security)

It looks like if `rand_batched.go` is initialized (this initializes altGetRandom) and `GOOS` is not plan9 (then `r.name = urandomDevice` it will return the length of the random array and not the content (which is surprising, why the length?)

see line 57:

```
if altGetRandom != nil && r.name == urandomDevice && altGetRandom(b) {
        return len(b), nil
    }
```

else it will simply return the content of the array which will be based on dev/random only if GOOS=plan9.

So why should it ever return `len(b)`?
Also it looks to me that most of the time it will use `dev/urandom` which is suboptimal... am I wrong (guess so because of docs, but help me understand)?

Comment: > I wanted to see when it generates rands from dev/random (more secure) and when it generates from dev/urandom(less security) I'm not sure this statement is true. See [Myth about urandom](https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about solving a specific problem but a question about implementation details of the stdlib which doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`altGetRandom` is used on systems where there is a system call to get random bytes, rather than depending on the existence of `/dev/urandom`.  This is *sometimes* useful in special environments (a chroot where there is no `/dev`, Docker-ish systems with weird/wrong `/dev`, FreeBSD jails with an incorrect `/dev` setup, etc.), and also is a bit faster than opening the file (as it does not go through quite as many system call layers), though in general one should just use the file.

The call in question is in an `io.Reader`-style function, whose job is to return the length of the block of bytes read, and any error.  When using the system call, the OS fills in—or is assumed to fill in—the array `b` completely, so `len(b)` is the correct result.